# Kylin packages has been replaced

Tags: software-installation, kylin

I have a broken desktop beacuse of ubuntukylin-desktop package that is now deprecated.

Is the UKUI-desktop-environment the new replacement for that?

Comment: It seems so. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/make-ubuntu-look-like-windows-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `ubuntukylin-desktop` is the whole desktop, and if you just want to try UKUI, you can install it by:

```
$ sudo apt install ukui-desktop-environment
```